# The problem of binding a custom widget frame to the edges of the screen (Qt C++)

Tags: c++, qt5, qwidget, qtstylesheets

The problem is that my application has a custom frame, i.e. the standard frame is disabled using (Qt::FramelessWindowHint), and my problem is that the standard frame has the ability to snap to the edges of the screen and automatically expand (by half or full screen), while providing a choice of which application will be open nearby.

Expected result(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MFtg.jpg)

How do I implement such functionality.
The custom frame itself is a widget, and several QLabels playing the role of borders
The functionality of moving the widget (frame) and changing its size is also individually implemented

Unfortunately I didn't find any information on the Internet

Comment: The image doesn't appear to be all that useful to this question  and images tend to attract scorn and derision. I'd remove it.  Replace it with code as text if the code has significance I'm missing.

Comment: This image shows exactly what I need, I want my widget to automatically stretch depending on the proximity to the borders of the screen, just like the notepad in this image, while giving me the choice of which of the active applications I want to place next to (for example, MVS or Edge, as in the image).